# Can a PWM solar charger use a battery as the source?

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, solar-charge-controller, 24v

For background, I am slowly migrating from 12v to 24v, but want to use my existing 12v inverters if possible, by having a 12v battery kept topped-up by the 24v batteries.

I have a decent MPPT controller charging the 24v from solar.

I have a couple of low-end 12/24 PWM controllers that are rated to take in solar at up to 50v (VOC I assume).

Can I use the 24v battery as the input (​in place of solar panels) to a PWM controller that is then connected to the 12v battery, and have it do it's pulse modulation thing to  control the voltage going into the 12v side?

Or might this effectively short the 12v 24v together, or otherwise result in potentially entertaining yet undesired consequences to the batteries, cabling, or controller?

Otherwise it'll probably mean an expensive DC-DC charger that I'd rather avoid.

Other suggestions appreciated.  Given the 12v load, I'd prefer to avoid taking a center tap from the 24v.

Edit to note: Pb batteries. Also, I could maybe use the 24v MPPT controller's load terminals (20a) rather than direct from the battery. Any difference?

[image: basic diagram as requested]

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing if the PWM charger just connects input to output with PWM, or includes a buck converter to step down the voltage. You could look inside. Got a scope?

Comment: Conversion between voltages should ideally use an active converter if the source is "stiff" . An MPPT converter meets this requirement - Vin X Iin x efficiency= Vout X Iout. A PWM converter typically connects the load for a portion of the time to achieve average effective voltage reduction. A pv panel acts as a current source and is able to be treated in this manner. But connecting a 24v battery for 50% of the  time to a 12v load is liable to destroy battery and load. Adding a series inductor and a diode from source to ground (non-conducting normally) produces a buck converter.